# ServiceStack BasicAuth returning 401 with client_credentials

Tags: .net, postman, servicestack, http-status-code-401

I have an remote endpoint that requires basic auth and client_credentials in the grant_type.

In Postman I can see the headers and body look like this:

```
Request Headers:
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  Authorization: Basic <my Base64 encoded credentials>
  User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2
  Accept: "*/*"
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Postman-Token: <uuid>
  Host: <target url>
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  Content-Length: 29
  Connection: keep-alive

Request Body:
  grant_type=client_credentials
```

If I remove the request body, the endpoint returns 401.

When I do the following with the ServiceStack HttpUtils:

```
var response = url.PostToUrl(
  formData: $"grant_type:\"client_credentials\", 
  requestFilter: req =>
  {
    req.AddBasicAuth(key, secret);
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  });
```

I also get 401 Unauthorized exception, implying that the grant_type client_credentials is not being posted properly. What is needed to resolve this in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly realised the body needs to be name value pairs, so this is what is needed to replicate what is being sent by postman:

```
var response = url.PostToUrl(
  formData: new { grant_type = "client_credentials" }, 
  requestFilter: req =>
  {
    req.AddBasicAuth(key, secret);
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  });
```